# Can Weibull Analysis be applied on random sample data?

Tags: statics, failure-analysis

I'm dealing with a sample on which I want to perform a Weibull analysis to get the median time to failure. The samples vary more or less continuously in their age as shown in the plot.
Is the type of analysis applicable here? If so, how does one go about it?

[image]

Comment: Weibull analysis is used for wind speed - is that continuous?

Comment: I guess so :)
But wind speed doesn't fail, so doesn't really help me here

Comment: I am baffled by your use of the word continuous. If you measure any quantity on a set of samples and order the quantities from the lowest to the highest, you will always get a very similar plot. What is continuous about it? Also, what type of failure are we dealing with here?

Comment: Excuse the poor wording, there is of course nothing continuous here in the mathematical sense. The data is actually subscription churn. So the failure is a customer having canceled a subscription where the others are still subscribed.

Comment: Does age continue to increase after failure?